# Xcos throws "Undefined variable: scifunc_block_m" message in console

Tags: scilab, xcos

When I run a Xcos model containing a scifunc_block_m block  like shown below
[image: xcos_model]
I get an error message relating to data dimensions inconsistency:

> "Data dimensions are inconsistent:"
> " Variable size=[1,1]"
> "Block output size=[100,1]."

But when I double click in the block in order to see what can I change to make the dimensions correct I get a message in the console saying

> Undefined variable: scifunc_block_m

What bugs me is that *scifunc_block_m* is not the name of any variable, but rather the name of the block itself like can be seen [in the official docs.](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/ru_RU/scifunc_block_m.html)
Of course I double checked that nowhere in my function *phase_shifter* neither anywhere else I have any variable named like that.

I tried with Scilab 6.1.1 and 6.1.0 believing that it might be a bug from apparently not.

Comment: Cam you share the diagram (.zcos file) ?

Comment: Please find it here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f01cff8ef47e1c0fc248be91648ad72020220113103840/f548f3

Answer (score 0):

In your `phase_shifter.sce` file generating the input variable,
the `signalIn` variable does not comply with the `From Workspace` block requirements, whose documentation says that the input variable

- must be a structure with `time` and `values` fields
- `.time` must be a column vector, and in your case
- `.values` must also be a column

So,

```
t = (0:1/fs:Npp/fs - 1/fs);       // time vector 
signalIn = A*%e^(%i*w*t);
```

should be replaced with

```
t = (0:1/fs:Npp/fs - 1/fs)';       // time column vector
signalIn = struct("time",t, "values",A*%e^(%i*w*t));
```

This fixes the inconsistent dimensions message.

In addition, i am not able to reproduce your issue about `Undefined variable: scifunc_block_m`. The parameters interface opens as expected.
You may get this kind of messages if you try to run some xcos parts out of xcos, without beforehand loading xcos-related libraries.

Then, we get an unclear `"Output should be of complex type."` message on the `From workspace` block.
By the way, you try to plot some complex values. Please have a look to the MATMAGPHI block before entering MUX: https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/MATMAGPHI.html